F1 STEM OPT to F1 visa
I was on STEM OPT. My employment ended on February 2, 2024. I had 118 days of remaining unemployment left. I used my allocated unemployment days as allowed until May 30, 2024. My new I-20 was issued on May 31,2024 and I am starting my Master’s program in the Fall.
My school's immigration advisor advise that a new I-20 would then effectively end my STEM OPT and I can stay in the US with the valid I-20 as long as I begin my program within 5 months of issuing the I-20 (which I am planning to). However, my DSO emailed me about being out of status which I am not sure how. My question is am I still in legal status? And what are my next steps? Thank you

Is it the same school?
